# Upload an app's update to the app store !

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have an app that is already existing on the app store ,But now i made its updates means i updated its UI its OS compatibality and other thing that will make help to run on the newer os now i want to put it on as a update to the existing user of the app and if a user have never this application then it will be a fresh application to him,How can i do that .? i was planning to make its plist version 1.2 but i think it will then not replace the app from the app store and for a new user there will be 2 app for the same build. HOw can we do that .......

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're over thinking this.

Increment your version number.

Log into iTunes Connect. Click on your application. Click the 'Add Version' button.

Go through the steps to submit your latest build with it's updated version. Once approved new users will be able to download it, and existing users will be able to update to it. There will not be two versions on the app store - just one; your latest.

Apple have thought this through for you ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you update your app on the AppStore the old version is removed once the update is approved. The new version will replace the existing one. Your app will not show up in the AppStore with 2 different versions.

Users who have the old version will see an update. New users will only be able to install the newly added update.

Comment: Thanks Yannick ...... then i just have to add the new build without doing any changes in the plist and so ... then it will go as an update to the existing user and new for the nwer user ....

Comment: You should increase the version number, you won't be able to add an update without increasing the version number actually.